# growpart "failed to get start sector" on expanding partition

Tags: amazon-ec2

Using the instructions located: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html

I can run:

```
lsblk
nvme0n1                                                                                            
259:1    0  200G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1                                                                                        
259:2    0    1M  0 part
└─nvme0n1p2                                                                                        
259:3    0  100G  0 part /
```

I then attempt to grow nvme0n1p2 by running:

```
growpart /dev/nvme0n1 3
FAILED: disk=/dev/nvme0n1 partition=3: failed to get start sector
```

Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong? Running this as root. I read the other similar threads but was unable to resolve based on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because partition 3 does not exist.

The command you run is

```
growpart /dev/nvme0n1 3
```

How ever the first device is the drive. The number ( in this case 3 ) is the partition number. As you can see by the output of the lsblk command there is only 2 partitions. Hence the output of can't find partition

```
  nvme0n1    -> device                                                                                        
259:1    0  200G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1                                                                                        
259:2    0    1M  0 part -> first partition ( leave this alone )
└─nvme0n1p2                                                                                        
259:3    0  100G  0 part / -> your root partition and what we want to grow in order to add room
```

The command you need to run is

```
growpart /dev/nvme0n1 2
```

As this will enlarge the partition assigned to /. You can continue to follow this guide after this